# Iterator map with HashMap lookup. Fail on any key not present

Tags: hashmap, iterator, rust

I have a `String` with colon-separated values. Each sub-string should be a key in a map. I want to write a function that converts the `String` into a `Vec` of map values, or a failure if any key is not present.

My attempt so far is incomplete, but I'm taking it in small steps. The first step is to convert the string into a vector of optional `u32`s. (This may not the best approach):

```
fn parse(string: &String, lookup: HashMap<String, u32, FastHasher>) -> Vec<Option<u32>> {
    string.split(":").map(|s: &str| lookup.get(s)).collect()
}
```

This results in

```
error: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<std::option::Option<u32>>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::option::Option<&u32>>` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
 --> <anon>:8:52
  |>
8 |>     string.split(":").map(|s: &str| lookup.get(s)).collect()
  |>                                                    ^^^^^^^
note: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<std::option::Option<u32>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::option::Option<&u32>`
```

I believe this means I need to import or write my own from-iterator behaviour for `Option<&u32>`, right?

After I've done that, how can I wrap in an `Ok` or `Err` depending upon the presence of any `None`s?

Comment: Did you forget the return type?

Comment: I omitted it to see what problem I have with the statement as it is. I had a return type in some long distant iteration of this code. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to return the references, you should specify lifetimes explicitly:

```
pub fn parse<'a, 'b>(string: &'a str, lookup: &'b HashMap<String, u32>) -> Vec<Option<&'b u32>> {
    string.split(":").map(|s| lookup.get(s)).collect()
}
```

Regarding the second part of the question about the conversion to `Result` type:

> And after I've done that, how can I wrap in an `Ok` or `Err` depending
>   upon the presence of any `None`s?

This can be done by folding and accumulating the results into `Ok<Vec<u32>>`. Following example illustrates the idea. See [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c9eaef90d27efa7c205f1d5eba6d6554&version=stable&backtrace=0) runnable example.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::result::Result;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ParseError {
    key: String,
}

impl ParseError {
    fn new(k: &str) -> ParseError {
        ParseError { key: k.to_owned() }
    }
}

fn parse(string: &str, lookup: &HashMap<String, u32>) -> Result<Vec<u32>, ParseError> {
    string.split(":")
        .fold(Ok(Vec::new()), |res, s| {
            let mut vec = try!(res);
            match lookup.get(s) {
                Some(&v) => {
                    vec.push(v);
                    Ok(vec)
                }
                None => Err(ParseError::new(s)),
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`HashMap::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) method returns an optional *reference* to the value inside of the map. So you have an iterator over `Option<&u32>`, but you want to have an iterator over `Option<u32>`. This is done by saying:

```
lookup.get(s).cloned()
//           ^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes your current code compile.

---

To answer the question in your title: there is a neat little [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) impl:

```
impl<A, V> FromIterator<Option<A>> for Option<V> where V: FromIterator<A>
```

This means, that,  for example, you can collect an iterator over items of types `Option<u32>` into `Option<Vec<u32>>`. This is exactly what you want! So just change your return type:

```
fn parse(string: &str, lookup: &HashMap<String, u32, FastHasher>) -> Option<Vec<u32>> {
//                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    string.split(":").map(|s| lookup.get(s).cloned()).collect()
}
```

You can try the working code [here on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=343ba1e477f1ed2402f5772ff01deab7&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

Also note the following, question-independent changes I made:

- The `string` argument is `&str` now instead of `&String`. There is practically no reason for ever passing `&String` instead of `&str`, so the latter is preferred for being more generic.
- The explicit type annotation of the closure argument is not required.
- You probably want to pass a reference to the `HashMap`, as your function does not need to own it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid this issue, instead of `Vec<Option<&u32>>` you could just return `Vec<Option<u32>>`:

```
fn parse(string: &String, lookup: HashMap<String, u32>) -> Vec<Option<u32>> {
    string.split(":").map(|s: &str| if let Some(&e) = lookup.get(s) { Some(e) } else { None }).collect()
}
```

Which, as Matthieu suggested, can be simplified to:

```
string.split(":").map(|s: &str| lookup.get(s).cloned()).collect()
```

I'm not sure if it adds value if you wrap it in a `Result`; you can easily check for `None` afterwards:

```
let v = vec![Some(1), None, Some(3)];
println!("{:?}", v.contains(&None));
```

Comment: Note: you can use `Option::cloned` to move from an `Option<&T>` to an `Option<T>`, this makes for shorter code: `string.split(":").map(|s: &str| lookup.get(s).cloned()).collect()`

Comment: Didn't know about that, very handy; I'll include it in the answer.